# How can I declare variables to be of OpenGL's GLuint type in Eclipse for Android programs?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, types, opengl-es

I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0.

"GLES20.GLuint test_type;" gets an error: "GLES20.GLuint cannot be resolved to a type."

I need variables of this type to refer to things like framebuffers, textures, and depthbuffers.

Answer (score 1):

The Java OpenGL bindings in Android do not use those types. They are just plain Java `int` types. You can confirm this by looking at the definition of functions in the documentation of `GLES20`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES20.html

Picking a couple of examples for framebuffer objects:

```
public static void glGenFramebuffers(int n, int[] framebuffers, int offset);
public static void glBindFramebuffer(int target, int framebuffer);
```

You can see that the types are simply `int` for object names, where the C bindings use `GLuint` in the same place.